# The optimal way for creating wizard-like form in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-forms

I am creating a wizard-like form in React. I want it to display another select only when user selects an option in a previous dropdown. Currently my selection works, but I am using a lot of useState hooks here. As eventually I want to have around 10 selects, I think that as much as 10 useStates may not be the best option.
Can you please check out my code and give me some tips that would make it better/explain why such change would make it better?

Below I post my code, it works in codesandbox with bootstrap 4.2.1 and react-select 2.2.0:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";

import "./styles.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

const options1 = [
  { label: "1", value: 1 },
  { label: "2", value: 2 }
];

const options2 = [
  { label: "3", value: 3 },
  { label: "4", value: 4 }
];

const options3 = [
  { label: "5", value: 5 },
  { label: "6", value: 6 }
];

const options4 = [
  { label: "7", value: 7 },
  { label: "8", value: 8 }
];

const App = () => {
  const [showSecond, setShowSecond] = useState(false);
  const [showThird, setShowThird] = useState(false);
  const [showFourth, setShowFourth] = useState(false);
  const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false);

  const renderSecond = () => {
    if (showSecond) {
      return (
        <div className="form-group row mt-2">
          <label className="col-4">Select 2</label>
          <Select
            onInputChange={updateSecond}
            className="col-8"
            options={options2}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  const renderThird = () => {
    if (showThird) {
      return (
        <div className="form-group row mt-2">
          <label className="col-4">Select 3</label>
          <Select
            onInputChange={updateThird}
            className="col-8"
            options={options3}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  const renderFourth = () => {
    if (showFourth) {
      return (
        <div className="form-group row mt-2">
          <label className="col-4">Select 4</label>
          <Select
            onInputChange={updateFourth}
            className="col-8"
            options={options4}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  const updateFirst = () => {
    // update some data
    setShowSecond(true);
  };

  const updateSecond = () => {
    // update some data
    setShowThird(true);
  };

  const updateThird = () => {
    // update some data
    setShowFourth(true);
  };

  const updateFourth = () => {
    // update some data
    setShowButton(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="col-12">
        <form className="form">
          <div className="form-group row mt-2">
            <label className="col-4">Select 1 </label>
            <Select
              className="col-8"
              onInputChange={updateFirst}
              options={options1}
            />
          </div>
          {renderSecond()}
          {renderThird()}
          {renderFourth()}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

As I am learning React, every suggestion will be very appreciated!

Comment: If your code is working and you arent seeking help on a specific problem please post to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You seem to have an array of an array of options, which all seem to be doing the same thing, use very similar visualizations, there is quite some possibility for refactoring here